# Files missing from a git clone

Tags: git

So here's what happened:

On machine A, I cloned a shared git repository.  Then I started a new branch, added a directory with a bunch of files in it, committed, and pushed the new branch.

On machine B I then cloned the same shared repository, created a remote tracking branch for the new branch I'd pushed, and pulled.

Somehow, certain subdirectories of the directory I added at A didn't show up in B -- even though other subdirectories, ones that were added in the same commit, did.

Going back to A, I tried to git add the directories that didn't show up.  Nothing happens.  I tried git log on those same directories -- the output is empty.

Any ideas what happened, and how I can fix it?

Comment: Do the directories that didn't show up contain files or are they empty directories?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are they empty directories? Git won't track an empty directory.

You can also look to make sure they're not being ignored in a `.gitignore` file. Git won't add ignored file (unless forced).

Comment: Bah!  No, my bad, turns out they are empty directories :P  Thanks for getting me to double-check.  /me thwaps self

Answer (score 12):

If you end up with a new directory with a .git directory inside it but no files in the new directory, then perhaps running "git checkout master" will cause the files to appear.

Comment: this answer was helpful - if you are using git flow, also consider the possibility of "git checkout develop" to get the most updated files

Comment: this helped as well. had to also do `git fetch` first before doing `git checkout master`